# Why equal value $ AC^T , \det(A)I $?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 5\end{bmatrix}$$

C is cofactor matrix.
$$AC^T = \det(A)I$$

why are each equal? I want to know prove.

Comment: Isn't that definition of $A^{-1}$ simply?

Comment: No. The definition of $A^{-1}$ is a matrix $B$ with $AB = BA = I$, if such a matrix exists. Once you know it exists, it's easy to prove it's unique, so we can call it "the inverse" rather than "an inverse".

Comment: @KushalBhuyan You are thinking of $\mathbf A^{-1} = | \mathbf A |^{-1} \mathbf C^\top$

Answer (score 1):

For an off-diagonal entry $ij$, where $i \ne j$, the product of the $i$th row of $A$ with the $j$th column of $C$ is just the determinant of the matrix consisting of all but the $j$th row of $A$, followed by the $i$th row (or perhaps the negative of this). That matrix has the $ith$ row of $A$ appearing twice, so its determinant is zero. Hence all off-diagonal entries are zero. I'll let you think about a similar argument for the on-diagonal entries.